# lua for windows read serial(RS-232) data

Tags: windows, lua, serial-port

I want to read serial data using Lua programing on windows
How do you that ?
So I want the instructions of the program.
Thanks you for our answers.

Answer (score 2):

To read serial data you need a C library such as [luars232](https://luarocks.org/modules/luarocks/luars232), [rs232](https://luarocks.org/modules/moteus/rs232) or [luaserial](https://luarocks.org/modules/javalikescript/luaserial)

Disclaimer: I wrote the last one